# How to get a data value between node tags

Tags: xml, xpath

Relatively new to XPath, but really need a help and appreciate your hand.

I have following XML file piece:

```
<div id="current">

     <b> Current Data Ratio:</b>
     17.35
     <span class="neg">-0.23 (-0.84%)</span>
     <div id="timestamp">4:29 pm EST, Fri Jan  9</div>
</div>
```

I want to get data value 17.35. My XPath code below:

```
     Node external_node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//div[@id='current']", xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
    if(null != external_node) {
        NodeList nodeList = external_node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; null!=nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node internal_node = nodeList.item(i);
            if(internal_node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName() + " : " + internal_node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()); 

        }
    }
```

then what I get is:

```
b : Current Data Ratio:

span : -0.23 (-0.84%)

div : 4:29 pm EST, Fri Jan  9
```

the data 17.35 cannot be obtained. I changed Node type to Node.TEXT_NODE like this:

if(internal_nod.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE

then I get nothing returned. Then I tried to use text() function, it seems no help either. Any help needed.

Comment: XML can be formatted the same way as any other piece of code - indent it by four spaces. I've done that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
<div id="current">

     <b> Current Data Ratio:</b>
     17.35
     <span class="neg">-0.23 (-0.84%)</span>
     <div id="timestamp">4:29 pm EST, Fri Jan  9</div>
</div>
```

Selecting nodes with this XPath expreession `//div[@id='current']/text()`  yields the wanted result `17.35`

Comment: Anders, tried with these two lines: Node external_node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//div[@id='current']/text()", xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
        System.out.println(external_node.getNodeValue()); but get nothing back

Comment: I javn't run you program in java, just used the Notepad++ tool`XPathenizerNPP` to run the XPath query - and there it works, so maybe the issue is in your Java code, and not the XPathExpression. I would *highly* recommend that you use the debugger to debug code, instead of relying on printouts.